# What to do when autofocus on Canon 85mm f/1.8 not working?

Tags: lens, canon, autofocus, troubleshooting, repair

My Canon 85mm's AF isn't working. But here's the thing, it recognizes there's a lens mounted, it gives focus confirmation, and I can even set the aperture, but it does NOT recognize that it's an AF lens. in fact it shows MF regardless of the position of the switch. What do I do ?

If it comes to sending it to Canon, how much is that likely to cost?

Comment: Have you cleaned the various electrical contacts on the mount?

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning the contacts on the lens and the camera (carefully!): even if it looks clean and free of dust, there can still be some layer of whatever that can interfere with the connection sufficiently for the camera not to fully recognise the lens.